# Did we lose the "not about politics" close reason?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, close-reasons

Previously we had a close reason which read:

> This question does not appear to be about governments, policies and political processes within the scope defined in the [help center.](https://politics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

This seems to have disappeared:

[image]

Could we have this back please? It's probably *the* most common close reason after "primarily opinion based"

Comment: Ohh, I'm [late again](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3119/2984) :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This default reason was automatically disabled [when we added the new close reasons](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3094/what-custom-close-reasons-should-we-have). We were not aware that this would happen. I already re-added it as a 3rd custom close-reason. It just needs to be approved by another mod.

Edit: It's back.