# Can censorship of this site by the Liberal Democrats be prosecuted?

Tags: discussion

Can censorship of this site by the Liberal Democrats be prosecuted?

Because I want to take this picture to the US Senate and crucify the Liberal Democrat Party.

[image: Censorship]

I want to accuse this site of organized censorship.

Comment: Are you literally asking if you can prosecute the site for deleting your question? If so, that's more of a legal question that doesn't fit our meta site.

Comment: Well, maybe you can explain in your question more specifically what you feel is the problem. I mean, when I'm gone someone else will take my position as moderator and they might make the same mistake. I'm not even sure what if anything my mistake was in this case, so they might not either. I suggest that you be more detailed in your question.

Answer (score 10):

> Can censorship of this site by the Liberal Democrats be prosecuted?

Nope, what law did we break? Just in case you were going to say first amendment, that only applies to governments

> Because I want to take this picture to the US Senate and crucify the Liberal Democrat Party.

1. Good luck getting the senate to even recognize who you are
2. Crucify the liberal democrat party could reasonably interpreted as a death threat. Those *can* be prosecuted FYI.

> I want to accuse this site of organized censorship.

Guilty as charged, we censor stuff that’s off topic. And that’s **on purpose**. We don’t like [push questions](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3094/what-custom-close-reasons-should-we-have/3099#3099) here (which your question blatantly is). Any other type of [off topic question](https://politics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) will also be removed (aka censored here). That’s for one simple reason:

## This is the wrong place to ask those questions.

If you want to ask these, you can go to reddit, or some other site. However, that’s off topic for stack exchange. Sorry.