# Are there guidelines about the topicality of local politics?

Tags: discussion, scope

Most of the questions here are questions with a broad interest, covering national-level politics as well as the politics of first-order administrative divisions such as states, provinces, and territories. Are questions about lower (or even much lower) level politics and political processes allowed on this site? For example, suppose I have a question about the politics of the locally-elected school board of a small coal mining town in West Virginia (population 5,000). My question is about politics (and not about cheesecake or something), asked in good faith, and sufficiently specific, narrow, and non-opinion-based to not fall under any of the standard network-wide close reasons. Is my question on-topic as a question about politics or off-topic because hardly anyone cares about such low-level and low-impact politics?

To be clear, I am aware that questions about low-level politics in obscure, lightly-populated rural areas are not likely to get lots of high-quality answers, but that is not what I'm asking. I'm asking if such questions are sufficiently bad that they should be preemptively *closed* rather than left for months or years waiting for someone capable of writing a good answer to bump into it.

I did find [this](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3109/9423) poorly-received proposal to add a "Too Local" close reason, but it is not clear whether that means that the community fully approves of such questions. Our [on-topic](https://politics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) guidance does not indicate any specific minimum "level" of politics for topicality.

If "too local" is a valid reason to close a question, are there guidelines as to *how* local a question can be without running afoul of the close reason? For example, would a question about the mayor of Chicago be allowed? How about the mayor of Rapid City, South Dakota?

Comment: You can always use a custom close argument such as "There isn't adequate information on the internet to make heads or tails of this very local question". If enough people agree with you, the question will be closed. Do not be afraid to use the custom close option. It is available on almost all (all???) SE sites.

Answer (score 9):

As far as I have seen there are no restrictions on local politics as long as it meets all other criteria for the site. It doesn't matter if you are asking a question about a small town or a large country rather what the question is asking.

The only problem is that when talking about a small town it might be hard if not possible to get the needed information to answer the question. While there can be a lot of information about the mayor of a large city there is normally not much about one of a small city.

Comment: It should maybe be said that we do not have many very localized questions about towns, more about rather minor known politician or political figures maybe (like about what some news moderator might have said). All in all the number of questions that might not be of much interest is relatively low.

Comment: @Trilarion I agree that we do not have many questions at this level but that does not indicate if they are on or off topic.